# How to decode Chinese hex string into Chinese characters or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

I am working on a Rails app.

I am using an API that returns some Chinese provinces.
The API returns the provinces in hex strings, for example:

```
{ "\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC" => "some data" }
```

My JavaScript calls a controller that returns this hash. I put all the province strings into a dropdown but the strings show up as a black diamond with a question mark in the middle. I am wondering how do I convert the Ruby hex string into actual Chinese characters, 北京? Or if possible, can I convert the hex string in JavaScript into Chinese characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bytes `\xE5\x8C\x97` are the UTF-8 representation of `北` and `\xE4\xBA\xAC` is the UTF-8 representation of `京`. So this string:

```
"\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC"
```

is `北京` if the bytes are interpreted as UTF-8. That you're seeing hex codes instead of Chinese characters suggests that the string's encoding is binary:

```
> s = "\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC"
 => "北京" 
> s.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
> s.force_encoding('binary')
 => "\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC"
```

So this API you're talking to is speaking UTF-8 but somewhere your application is losing track of what encoding that string is supposed to be. If you [force the encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) to be UTF-8 then the problem goes away:

```
> s.force_encoding('utf-8')
 => "北京"
```

You should fix this encoding problem at the very edge of your application where it reads data from this remote API. Once that's done, everything should be sensible UTF-8 everywhere that you care about. This should fix your JavaScript problem as well as JavaScript is quite happy to work with UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this: [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-decode)
rb:

```
 2.1.2 :002 > require 'uri'
     => true 
    2.1.2 :003 > URI.decode("\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC")
     => "北京"
```

js: `decodeURIComponent(URIstring)`

Comment: This seems to work in IRB, but when  I return this data as JSON via Rails controller, the strings turn into black diamond characters (when I console.log the JavaScript strings). Thus, when I use decocdeURIComponent, it has no effect.

Comment: And in JS, decodeURIComponent("\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC") returns "åäº¬".

Comment: You might want to evaluate `"\xE5\x8C\x97\xE4\xBA\xAC"` in `irb` without bothering with `URI.decode`...